# Class decorator not being called everytime

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

A seemingly easy thing which i cant get around.

```
registry  =  {}

def register(cls):
    registry[cls.__clsid__] = cls
    print cls
    return cls

@register
class Foo(object):
    __clsid__ = "123-456"

    def bar(self):
        pass
c=Foo()
d=Foo()

e=Foo()
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Now i expect decorator to be called `3` times.Why has it been called only `once`.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve here? A class object is created just once; you are not creating more classes, you are creating *instances*. Those `Foo()` calls don't re-execute the `class` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class decorator is applied *when the class is created*, not each time an instance is created.

The `@register` line applies to the `class Foo(object):` statement only. This is run just *once*, when the module is imported.

Creating an instance does not need to re-run the class statement because instances are just objects that keep a reference to the class (`type(c)` returns the `Foo` class object); instances are not 'copies' of a class object.

If you want to register *instances* you'll either have to do so in the `__init__` or the `__new__` method of a class (which can be decorated too). `__new__` is responsible for creating the instance, `__init__` is the hook called to initialise that instance.

Comment: But isnt `class` just a template which comes into existence when `object` is created

Comment: @vks: no, a class is an object. Calling that object then produces an instance which keeps a reference to the class. Through that reference attributes are resolved, which is how methods are found, for example.

Comment: hey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python we have singleton decorator for class....which allows only one object...if decorator is called only once,then how does it manage this?

Comment: The class decorator in that question doesn't return a class object. It returns a function instead. You don't *have* to return a class object from a class decorator, at all. You just have to return *something* that'll then be bound to the class name.

Comment: ok but still when i call for new object it wont get called right? then how it is this getting handled?

Comment: Please do read the code of the class decorator; the function that's returned would be called instead, and it is responsible for creating an instance (and it'll only create *one*).

Answer (score 2):

The class decorator is being applied to the class itself, and it is applied only once, when the class is defined. Basically, it processes the class definition and produces a new class.

So you'd only process it once.